# Naming a selector

Tags: jquery

I have rows of select fields which gets added dynamically whenever I click a button, and I have named them accordingly to which row they belong to, each time select button is triggered.

There will therefore be select fields such as...

```
<select name='fieldname1'></select>
<select name='fieldname2'></select>
```

And so on.

I would like to add the option fields for them within the same method. How do I initiate the method? I am currently trying to refer to the selector via their name.Currently I have done this:

```
 $("select[name=fieldname+" currentrow +"]").html("<option value='ISARYear'>ISAR Year</option>" etc.
```

'Currentrow' is a variable that has been declared earlier find out the current rows / number of select lists. I believe I have got the syntax wrong. How do I then refer newly added select list?

JSFiddle Here: http://jsfiddle.net/kosherjellyfish/JsW3a/

Comment: You have a syntax error there. You need to change `$("select[name=fieldname"+ currentrow +"]")`

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/VuP4z/1/

Comment: ...and http://jsfiddle.net/JsW3a/1/ - you're mostly there, just a few syntax errors. Including the jQuery lib in your fiddle would help too

Comment: Thanks guys... I saw my error :P